# API POST call which uploads an excel sheet

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to make a POST call from a ruby script which upload through my authserver api an excel with roles from the same directory. I try to reproduce the call from postman without luck, and it looks something like this:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://authserver:8080/svc/batchImport/v2/direct/roles")
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request["Content-Type"] = 'application/xlsx'
request["externalTenantId"] = tntid
request["uid"] = uid
request.body ={
      "file"=> "Roles.xlsx",
      "importMode"=> "OVERWRITE",
      "tenantId"=> tntid,
    }.to_json
response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https") do |http|
  http.request(request)
end
puts response.code
puts response.body
```

So basically tntid and uid will be the header for the call and the body will be a form-data.Please find below error I get:

```
500
{"errorCode":["com.domain.common.exception.DefaultErrorCode","UNEXPECTED_ERROR"],"errorMessage":"Unknown server error occurred.","developerMessage":null,"moreInfo":null}
```

Comment: what's the error.

Comment: 500 error, the call it's working with POSTMAN, I manage to translate other calls from postman in ruby but this upload file it's not working. It would be great if it will work from system() with a bash curl also.

Comment: Show the error in the server logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%x[curl -s -X POST -H 'uid: #{uid}' -H 'externalTenantId: #{tntid}' -F 'file=@#{roles}' -F 'importMode=OVERWRITE' -F 'tenantId=#{tntid}' http://#{iam}:8080/iamsvc/batchImport/v2/direct/roles]